# How to make (multi part) node fill color depend on its content?

Tags: tikz-styles

In the following MWE i like to change fill and text color depending on content of a cell similarly as I manage to change text color for this particular cell content:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\tikzset{HDLC/.style = {
        start chain = 1 going left,
okvir/.style n args = {3}{rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
        text depth=0.5ex, inner sep=1.2pt, outer sep=0mm,
        font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
        align=center, draw=gray!80,
        text width=##1,
        text=blue,
        %%%%%%%%%%
        %if ##3 is I than
        rectangle split part fill={teal!60!black,white}, text=teal!60!black,
        % else
        % rectangle split part fill={cyan!60!black,white}, text=cyan!60!black,
        node contents={\nodepart{one}\vphantom{/tip}\textcolor{white}{##2}
                       \nodepart{two}\vphantom{/tip}\ifstrequal{##2}{tip}
                                        {\textcolor{black!60!red}{\textbf{##3}}}
                                        {##3}
                       },% end of node contents
        },
   PP/.style n args = {3}{okvir={##1}{##2}{##3},
        on chain=1},
    }}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[HDLC, node distance=2mm and 0mm]
\node (a) [PP={7mm}{N\textsubscript{R}}{0}]% should use teal!60!black
        node[PP={7mm}{P/F}{P}]
        node[PP={7mm}{N\textsubscript{S}}{4}]
        node[PP={5mm}{tip}{I}];
\node(b) [PP={7mm}{N\textsubscript{R}}{0}, below=of a]% should use cyan!60!black
        node[PP={7mm}{P/F}{P}]
        node[PP={7mm}{N\textsubscript{S}}{4}]
        node[PP={5mm}{tip}{S}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

In the top image i lake to have first row color in `teal!60!black! and in the bottom  as it is now. The text color in cells (except in the first) i like to have the same color as is color of the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your question, you can define a style `ifstrequal` with four arguments `{str1}{str2}{style if equal}{style if not}` and then use it inside your `okvir` like in the following code :

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\tikzset{
  % ---------
  ifstrequal/.code n args={4}{
    \ifstrequal{#1}{#2}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#4}}
  },
  % ---------
  HDLC/.style = {
    start chain = 1 going left,
    okvir/.style n args = {3}{rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
      text depth=0.5ex, inner sep=1.2pt, outer sep=0mm,
      font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
      align=center, draw=gray!80,
      text width=##1,
      text=blue,
      % ---------
      ifstrequal={##3}{I}{
        rectangle split part fill={teal!60!black,white}, text=teal!60!black
      }{
        rectangle split part fill={cyan!60!black,white}, text=cyan!60!black
      },
      % ---------
      node contents={
        \nodepart{one}\vphantom{/tip}\textcolor{white}{##2}
        \nodepart{two}\vphantom{/tip}\ifstrequal{##2}{tip}
            {\textcolor{black!60!red}{\textbf{##3}}}
            {##3}
        },% end of node contents
    },
    PP/.style n args = {3}{okvir={##1}{##2}{##3},
      on chain=1},
    }}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[HDLC, node distance=2mm and 0mm]
\node (a) [PP={7mm}{N\textsubscript{R}}{0}]% should use teal!60!black
        node[PP={7mm}{P/F}{P}]
        node[PP={7mm}{N\textsubscript{S}}{4}]
        node[PP={5mm}{tip}{I}];
\node(b) [PP={7mm}{N\textsubscript{R}}{0}, below=of a]% should use cyan!60!black
        node[PP={7mm}{P/F}{P}]
        node[PP={7mm}{N\textsubscript{S}}{4}]
        node[PP={5mm}{tip}{S}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** inside the `ifstrequal` style you can use `every one node part` and `every two node part` styles to set separate styles for the two parts and avoid your `\ifstrequal` inside `node contents`.

Comment: Thank you very much! however, the same (similar) solution I test before I send my answer an receive error "missing endcsname". Meantime I upgraded my MikTeX, and your solution works. I need some time to see eventual difference between my tests and your solution ... (so far +1 :-) )

Comment: i found the difference why my attempt didn't work! thank you very much again!